# How to enable onpaste only for alphabetic letters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have got a task to disable the textbox from pasting.Only the alphabetic characters must be allow to paste.
My code is

```
<b>Name</b>
<input type="text" id="name" onpaste="return false"/>
```

By giving onpaste="return false" no values are pasted.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: $('input').bind('copy paste', function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
});

Comment: This will disable copy and paste

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with the [tag:jquery-validate] plugin.  Edited tags.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this code

```
$(".alphabetOnly").bind('paste', function(e) {
  var self = this;
  setTimeout(function(e) {
    var val = $(self).val();
    if (val != '0') {
      if (val.match(/^[0-9]+$/) != null) {
        $(".alphabetOnly").val("");
      }
      $(this).val(val);
    }
  }, 0);
});
```

I have updated the code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WSvhZ/6/)

Answer (score 2):

Made some mistakes before, this is working:

```
$('#name').bind('paste', function(){
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
        if(!/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test($(self).val()))
            $(self).val('');
    }, 0);    
});
```

You have to remove the `onpaste="return false"` from your html!

A working example can be found here: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GuhJN/)

Comment: @Nithu Hey man, i made some mistakes. Those are fixed and got it working!

Answer (score 2):

This code restrict pasting of other characters apart from numbers in the input field.On pasting a value to an input field, I'm testing the value with the regex, if the condition is true, the value will be set, or else i'm emptying the input value.In my case i had to restrict other characters apart from numbers, you can change the regex based on your requirement

```
$(".numbersOnly").bind('paste', function(e) {
        var self = this;
        setTimeout(function(e) {
            var val = $(self).val();
            if (val != '0') {
                var regx = new RegExp(/^[0-9]+$/);
                if (!regx.test(val)) {
                    $(".numbersOnly").val("");
                }
                $(this).val(val);
            }
        }, 0);
    });
```

Comment: A self explanatory answer is just awesome. So can you please explain a bit about your answer and how this code works.!

Comment: This code restrict pasting of other characters apart from numbers in the input field.On pasting a value to an input field,i'm testing the value with the regex,if the condition is true,the value will be set,or else i'm emptying the input value.In my case i had to restrict other characters  apart from numbers,you can change the regex based on your requirement

Answer (score 0):

Place a call to a function inside of your onpaste value.  Then, inside of that function, weed-out the non-alphabetic characters.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10972954/javascript-onpaste) for more details.

Comment: How would you go about weeding out the non alphabetic characters in the onpaste event. The `paste` event is fired before the input value changed. You would need a Timeout or something else to modify the input's value

Comment: Correct, a timeout is used in the referenced "this question" link.